# Modifying the codes in R

Tags: r

I hope this message finds you well.
I have recently written a code in R that perfectly works, but unfortunately, it is so time-consuming with big data since it is based on a loop. Now, I wonder how I can rewrite this code so that there is no need for a loop. I really appreciated it if anyone can help.

```
for (k in 1:nrow(migration)){
  migration$district[k]<-
    sample(0:30, size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=migration[k,7:37])
}
```

Comment: Without the probability you can do `migration$district <- sample(0:30, nrow(migration),replace = TRUE)`. For every row do you have a different probability values?

Comment: @RonakShah 
Every row is an individual who, based on their district, has 31 different probabilities. The total of these probabilities is 1. In fact, I want to know, by the end of the year, each individual stays in their district or not. If not, which district is her/his destination?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this case, using `apply` might be more efficient than a loop. An example running on a test dataset is:

```
#Make up some test data
n <- 10000
migration <- data.frame(lapply(1:37, function(x)runif(n)))
names(migration) <- c("district", paste0("col",2:37))

#Code from question
system.time(
  for (k in 1:nrow(migration)){
    migration$district[k]<-
      sample(0:30, size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=migration[k,7:37])
  }
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 1.99    0.01    2.00

#Alternative approach
system.time({
  migration$district <- apply(migration[7:37], 1, function(x){sample(0:30, size=1, replace = TRUE, prob=x)})
}
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.06    0.00    0.06
```